# Why does the second section of java code always takes considerably more time to run?

Tags: java, benchmarking

While trying to benchmark as suggested when I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294880/which-of-these-pieces-of-code-is-faster-in-java) question, I found that no matter what, whichever piece of code I tested second was dramatically longer by a factor of 1000 ns. I even swapped the pieces of code being tested to see if one really just was longer than the other, and the longer time swapped meaning it is placement in code that affects how long it runs. Here is my benchmark code:

```
public class JavaAsmTest
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int numOfTrials = 10;

        long [] codeATimes = new long [numOfTrials];
        long [] codeBTimes = new long [numOfTrials];
        for(int trial = 0; trial < numOfTrials; trial++)
        {
            {
                long startTime;
                long endTime;
                long deltaTime;
                startTime = System.nanoTime();
                for(int x = 0; x < 0x10000; x++)
                {
                    for(int y = 0; y < 0x10000; y++)
                    {
                        codeB(x, y); //the code being tested
                    }//end y loop
                }//end x loop
                endTime = System.nanoTime();
                deltaTime = endTime - startTime;
                codeBTimes[trial] = deltaTime;
            }//end codeB Trial
            {
                long startTime;
                long endTime;
                long deltaTime;
                startTime = System.nanoTime();
                for(int x = 0; x < 0x10000; x++)
                {
                    for(int y = 0; y < 0x10000; y++)
                    {
                        codeA(x, y); //the other code being tested
                    }//end y loop
                }//end x loop
                endTime = System.nanoTime();
                deltaTime = endTime - startTime;
                codeATimes[trial] = deltaTime;
            }//end codeA Trial

        }//end trial loop

        long codeASum = 0;
        long codeBSum = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < numOfTrials; x++)
        {
            codeASum += codeATimes[x];
            codeBSum += codeBTimes[x];
        }

        long codeAAvg = codeASum / numOfTrials;
        long codeBAvg = codeBSum / numOfTrials;

        System.out.println("codeA avg: " + codeAAvg);
        System.out.println("codeB avg: " + codeBAvg);

    }//end main

    private static void codeA(int a, int b)
    {
        int result = (a + b) & 0xFFFF;

        if(result == 0)
        {
            setZeroFlag(true);
        }
        else
        {
            setZeroFlag(false);
        }
        setSubtFlag(false);
        if((((a & 0x0FFF) + (b & 0x0FFF)) & 0x1000) != 0)
        {
            setHCarryFlag(true);
        }
        else
        {
            setHCarryFlag(false);
        }
    }

    private static void codeB(int a, int b)
    {
        int result = (a + b) & 0xFFFF;

        if(result == 0)
        {
            setZeroFlag(true);
        }
        else
        {
            setZeroFlag(false);
        }
        setSubtFlag(false);

        setHCarryFlag((((a & 0x0FFF) + (b & 0x0FFF)) & 0x1000) != 0);
    }

    private static void setZeroFlag(boolean flag)
    {
    }
    private static void setHCarryFlag(boolean flag)
    {
    }
    private static void setSubtFlag(boolean flag)
    {
    }
}
```

Please explain why this happens and how to prevent it to give me a realistic benchmark.

Comment: Micro benchmarking is hard. Instead of trying to do it yourself, use an existing framework such as Java Microbenchmarking Harness (JMH).

Comment: There isn't really a way to tell why it takes so much longer without additional tools. Java runs on a virtual machine where a lot of things happen in the background. There could be some optimalisation kicking in or the garbage collector might clean up all of the temporary values out of memory once the first method ended.

Comment: Believe it or not, for me with your exact code, **the first one takes more time** always... Eg: `codeA avg: 744046, codeB avg: 1117794`

Comment: The answer is most likely a JVM "warmup" effect, such as code loading, class initialization, heap resizing or JOT compilation.  But the best solution is to use an micro-benchmark framework that compensates for these effects.

Comment: The funnly thing is, OP's code never completes for me unless I add a println statement inside the trial loop. Very odd.

Comment: But OP, given you code you clearly assume many false things about how the JVM runs your code. By leaving the `set...` methods empty the JVM can declare your complete `codeA` and `codeB` methods as dead code and eliminate them. But that's just one thing you're doing wrong... Why don't you benchmark your actual code in a realistic setup and compare the two idioms? You probably won't notice any difference at all because you're worrying about performance at the wrong level.